# Get access to a ChildModel in Controller and View via a ParentModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not able to give Values to the ChildModel via the ParnetModel and access my ChildModel in the View. Or should I make a own ViewModel, for those values I need for it in the view?

Here is my ParentModel

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; }
    public List<ChildModel> ChildModelList { get; set; }
}
```

and a ChildModel

```
public class ChildModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller I have to fill the Parentmodel+the Childmodel and give it to the View

```
List<ParentModel> listparent = new List<ParentModel>();
listparent.Add(
    new ParentModel
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "abc",
        ChildModel.Number = 2,    // does not work
        ChildModelList.Number = 2 // does not work
    }
);
```

I don't know how to access the ChildModel here, when I want to add values for it.

In the View I have to access the Child too. I added the ParentModel with:

```
@model List<TestApp4.Models.ParentModel>
```

And then I would try to achieve them viea:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @item.Id
     @item.Name
     @item.ChildModel.Number
}
```

This does not work. Am I right, that the controller has to be a List because otherwise I cannot iterate over it in the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ChildModel is a class, so you have to create a new instance first.

And ChildModel is an generic list, so you have to create an instance of the list, and add an instance of the generic type

```
listparent.Add(
    new ParentModel
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "abc",
        ChildModel = new ChildModel {Number = 2},
        ChildModelList = new List<ChildeModel>(new[]{ 
                                 new ChildModel{Number=1}, 
                                 new ChildModel{Number= xxx}
                                })
    }
);
```

so in your view, you can have something like this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @item.Id
     @item.Name
     @item.ChildModel.Number //you may check for null if ChildModel is not always declared
     foreach(var cm in item.ChildModelList) {//nul check may also be usefull
        @c.Number
     }
}
```

You may create an instance of `ChildModelList` in the constructor of your `ParentModel` class , to be sure you have an existing instance of `ChildModelList`.

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public ParentModel() {
        ChildModelList = new List<ChildModel>();
    }
    //and even a ctor  with a given number to instanciate ChildModel
    public ParentModel(int childNumber) : this() {
        ChildModel = new ChildModel{Number = childNumber};
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ChildModel ChildModel { get; set; }
    public List<ChildModel> ChildModelList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you think this is the most elegant way to solve it or make an own viewmodel?

Comment: Well, for a single property, you should rather flatten it (a property ChildModelNumber, for example, to replace ChildModel.Number), but for the list, I guess you ain't got that choice.